# What happens if the signal frequency exceeds the sampling rate?

Tags: signal-processing, sampling, fft, signal-theory

As the title states, I was wondering what happens to the frequency contents of the sampled signal of a pure sinusoidal signal that exceeds the sampling rate.

I am familiar with the shannon theorem and the effect that a signal of say 0.75 times the sampling frequency would be mirrored at the nyquist frequency to turn out as a sampled signal of 0.25 times the sampling frequency, like shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYzrcbnZqaE

But what would happen if I turned up the signal frequency further than the sampling frequency, so that the "mirrored frequency" would exceed zero? Would the frequency of the signal "Bounce back" from the y axis once more and in effect bounce back an forth between the nyquist frequency and zero when increasing the signal frequency indefinitely?

Comment: In a word, aliasing. [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing)

Comment: I feel like you just read the title and not the whole question. I can't find a direct answer to my question in the wikipedia article, could you point me to it?

Comment: Figure 5 - "Graph of frequency aliasing, showing folding frequency and periodicity."

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. So if I understand the figure correctly, the assumption I made in my initial question is correct and the frequency of the sampled signal would in fact "bounce back and forth" between zero and the nyquist frequency when increasing the signal frequency indefinitely?

Comment: That's true only when you use a low-pass filter for reconstruction. You can also choose a bandpass filter -- see [Undersampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undersampling).

Comment: Thank you, that's all I wanted to know.

Comment: Another useful search term is "spectral folding". Which means, if you intend to make use of this, you usually want a bandpass filter to select ONE Nyquist-frequency wide slice of the spectrum ahead of the sampling process(ADC). Unless you're looking for the presence of a signal and don't care about its frequency or reproducing it correctly.

Comment: @user_1818839 I see! feel free to post a full answer based on your comment and I'll happily accept it.